# How to get fixed header to work in scrolling html table (when header has multiple rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I managed to get fixed header in scrolling table working with [this plugin](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/) (and also tried numerous other ones)... with a catch.

None of them work if our tables have multiple rows in the header.

eg

Think of a table like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    title of the table
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>col 1</th>
    <th>col 2</th>
    ...
  </tr>
  </thead>
  ...
```

When I take out either of the two rows in `<thead>`, the plugin I linked and many other solutions work. However, for some of the tables they HAVE to have both the column headers AND the table name, so removing one of the two simply isn't an option.

Is there a way to merge the two rows in the header to one in html?  Or is there a way to get the plugins to work nicely with multiple rows in the header? I have been googling around a ton on the scrolling tables with fixed headers, but I've yet to find any that works with multiple rows in the header.

Comment: you can't move the table name outside of the table?

Comment: Can you have a div in your header row that fakes as two rows, like put two vertically stacked divs inside that div, slap on a border-bottom on the top div and make it looks like 2 rows?

Comment: @andi Not allowed to :(  That was my first suggestion at work.

Comment: @whatissleep I'm not sure I understand what you mean - I still have very limited web dev experience. At the end of the day the scrolling part (aka the header) needs to have 2 rows - the top one having the title and the bottom one having the column headers.

Comment: I am suggesting to have 1 table row in the header, which contains 2 divs, stacked vertically, so it appears to be 2 table rows. The top div can have the title, the bottom div can have more divs inside that contains multiple column headers

Comment: @whatissleep pardon me for the newb question, but wouldn't that screw around with the bottom div's column header elements lining up properly with the columns in `<tbody>`?

Comment: @whatissleep well, I just tried your idea. Except that first div element will only go as far as the length of the first column instead of the whole thing... and colspan doesn't work on it.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem with this. If the table columns have variable widths, you probably need some javascript to fix the width of each div that contains the column title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this, the Table Title should take up the whole width if done this way

```
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <div id="table_head_div">

        <div id="table_title" style="height:50%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0;">Table Title</div>

        <div id="column_titles" style="height:50%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0;">
            <div class="column_title">column 1</div>
            <div class="column_title">column 2</div>
            <div class="column_title">column 3</div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </tr>
  </thead>
```